# Understanding solution with slots

Tags: slot

I am trying to find eigenvalues of a matrix. It has two symbols $k_1$ and $k_2$. I get this solution from mathematica

[image]

Reading the doucmentation, I know # is a placeholder, much like an input to an expression. But I have no inputs to give.

**My interpretation:**

There are 4 *Roots[expression,number]*. I imagine they correspond to the four eigenvalues. The #s represent the supposed input to be filled. What do they refer to?

**P.S.**: I'd like to point out that my question is more about interpretation. I am not able to understand the way #s are defined in mathematica and solution given here!

Comment: Whaat does ANCL mean?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but the root post deals with finding solution to radical or trancendental equations. I think mine is a radical one. Although the post did help me in understanding how the roots are given in pure functions, I still cannot understand how to identify what this solution represents. e.g. I would expect it to give me something like fourth root of k1 - something. That can be understood but in this I see k1 and k2 separate, then what needs to fo in #. maybe I dont still understand the concept of pure fucntions